# Voting blockchain smart contract, transaction dropped or replaced when interacting with contract using metamask but not with remix vm

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, metamask, remix-ide

Please point me to the right direction.

Below is the code for my voting contract that I have created in remix IDE. When interacting with `addCandidate` Method on remix VM it is working properly but when I try to use metamask with sepolia test network, I am always getting the error `Transaction Failed! Tranasaction replaced or dropped`

[image: Transaction failed message, metamask]

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

error CandidateAlreadyExists();
error AlreadyVoted();
error InvalidCandidate();
error NotRegisteredVoter();
error VoterAlreadyRegistered();
error OnlyManagerCanCall();
error InvalidAddress();
error InvalidName();
error InsufficientCandidates();

contract BlockchainVoting {
    address private manager;
    mapping(address => Voter) private voters;
    mapping(address => Candidate) private candidateLookup;
    Candidate[] private candidates;
    address[] private voterAddresses;

    constructor() {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    struct Voter {
        string name;
        address voterAddress;
        bool hasVoted;
    }

    struct Candidate {
        string name;
        address candidateAddress;
        uint256 votes;
    }

    function registerVoter(string memory voterName, address voterAddress) external onlyManager {
        if (voterAddress == address(0)) {
            revert InvalidAddress();
        }
        if (bytes(voterName).length == 0) {
            revert InvalidName();
        }
        if (voters[voterAddress].voterAddress != address(0)) {
            revert VoterAlreadyRegistered();
        }
        voters[voterAddress] = Voter(voterName, voterAddress, false);
        voterAddresses.push(voterAddress);
    }

    function registerVoters(string[] memory voterNames, address[] memory voterAddressesArray) external onlyManager {
        require(voterNames.length == voterAddressesArray.length, "Array length mismatch");

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < voterAddressesArray.length; i++) {
            address voterAddress = voterAddressesArray[i];
            string memory voterName = voterNames[i];

            if (voterAddress == address(0)) {
                revert InvalidAddress();
            }
            if (bytes(voterName).length == 0) {
                revert InvalidName();
            }
            if (voters[voterAddress].voterAddress != address(0)) {
                revert VoterAlreadyRegistered();
            }

            voters[voterAddress] = Voter(voterName, voterAddress, false);
            voterAddresses.push(voterAddress);
        }
    }

    function addCandidate(address candidateAddress, string memory name) external onlyManager {
        if (candidateAddress == address(0)) {
            revert InvalidAddress();
        }
        if (bytes(name).length == 0) {
            revert InvalidName();
        }
        if (candidateLookup[candidateAddress].candidateAddress != address(0)) {
            revert CandidateAlreadyExists();
        }

        Candidate memory newCandidate = Candidate({ name: name, candidateAddress: candidateAddress, votes: 0 });
        candidates.push(newCandidate);
        candidateLookup[candidateAddress] = newCandidate;
    }

    function addCandidates(address[] memory candidateAddresses, string[] memory names) external onlyManager {
        require(candidateAddresses.length == names.length, "Array length mismatch");

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < candidateAddresses.length; i++) {
            address candidateAddress = candidateAddresses[i];
            string memory name = names[i];

            if (candidateAddress == address(0)) {
                revert InvalidAddress();
            }
            if (bytes(name).length == 0) {
                revert InvalidName();
            }
            if (candidateLookup[candidateAddress].candidateAddress != address(0)) {
                revert CandidateAlreadyExists();
            }

            Candidate memory newCandidate = Candidate({ name: name, candidateAddress: candidateAddress, votes: 0 });
            candidates.push(newCandidate);
            candidateLookup[candidateAddress] = newCandidate;
        }
    }

    function vote(address candidateAddress) external {
        if (candidates.length < 2) {
            revert InsufficientCandidates();
        }
        Voter storage senderVoter = voters[msg.sender];

        if (senderVoter.voterAddress == address(0)) {
            revert NotRegisteredVoter();
        }
        if (senderVoter.hasVoted) {
            revert AlreadyVoted();
        }

        Candidate storage candidate = candidateLookup[candidateAddress];
        if (candidate.candidateAddress == address(0)) {
            revert InvalidCandidate();
        }

        candidate.votes++;
        senderVoter.hasVoted = true;
    }

    function getAllCandidates() external view returns (Candidate[] memory) {
        return candidates;
    }

    function getAllVoters() external view returns (Voter[] memory) {
        Voter[] memory voterList = new Voter[](voterAddresses.length);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < voterAddresses.length; i++) {
            voterList[i] = voters[voterAddresses[i]];
        }
        return voterList;
    }

    modifier onlyManager() {
        if (msg.sender != manager) {
            revert OnlyManagerCanCall();
        }
        _;
    }
}
```